# My rails tests produce gibberish output

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I just overtook a new project and the `rake test` produces a lot of gibberish output. Why is that the case? I tried removing all gems I don't know, but still my output is clouded. I am calling the test suite via `bundle exec rake test`.

Sample output - it's pages of this kind of stuff.

```
/Users/hendricius/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.22.5/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:98: warning: File.exists? is a deprecated name,
use File.exist? instead
/Users/hendricius/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.22.5/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:98: warning: File.exists? is a deprecated name,
use File.exist? instead
/Users/hendricius/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.22.5/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:98: warning: File.exists? is a deprecated name,
use File.exist? instead
/Users/hendricius/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.22.5/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:98: warning: File.exists? is a deprecated name,
use File.exist? instead
```

[image: screenshot of the tests running]

The ruby version from the `.ruby-version` file is `2.2.2`. The installed rails version is `3.2.22.5`.

My test gems are:

```
group :test, :development do
  # gem 'rack-mini-profiler'
  # gem 'minitest'
  gem 'minitest-rails'
  gem 'test-unit'
  gem 'shoulda'
  gem 'shoulda-matchers'
  gem 'fabrication'
  gem 'byebug'
end
```

I then double checked my `Rakefile`. It has the following content:

```
# Add your own tasks in files placed in lib/tasks ending in .rake,
# for example lib/tasks/capistrano.rake, and they will automatically be available to Rake.

require File.expand_path('../config/application', __FILE__)

WooWoop::Application.load_tasks

task default: [:test]
```

The only other thing I could imagine would be my `test_helper`. I pasted the contents below. It looks good.

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] = "test"
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require "rails/test_help"
require "minitest/rails"
require "minitest/pride"
require 'shoulda'
require 'shoulda/matchers'
# $VERBOSE=nil

# ActiveRecord::Migration.check_pending!
ActiveSupport::TestCase.test_order = :random
# Protractor test or even some dirty debugging in the rails console on test environment
# might have left some garbage on the DB. Lets make sure we start with a clean state.
# parses the response and returns it.
```

The only way I can silence the output is if I use `RUBYOPT=W0 TEST=test/unit/shop_test.rb be rake test`. Is that the only way since I am using rails 3 still?

**Update:**

I now tried to downgrade to ruby 2.0.0

I still get a lot of strange warnings I have never seen before.

```
/Users/hendricius/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p648/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/carrierwave-0.10.0/lib/carrierwave/uploader/configuration.rb:89: warning: instance variable @mount_on not in
itialized
/Users/hendricius/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p648/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/carrierwave-0.10.0/lib/carrierwave/mount.rb:243: warning: instance variable @previous_model_for_showcase_cov
er_picture not initialized
/Users/hendricius/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p648/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/carrierwave-0.10.0/lib/carrierwave/uploader/configuration.rb:89: warning: instance variable @mount_on not in
itialized
/Users/hendricius/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p648/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/carrierwave-0.10.0/lib/carrierwave/mount.rb:243: warning: instance variable @previous_model_for_manager_pict
ure not initialized
(eval):11: warning: instance variable @opening_hours_monday_from not initialized
(eval):2: warning: instance variable @opening_hours_monday_to not initialized
(eval):11: warning: instance variable @opening_hours_tuesday_from not initialized
(eval):2: warning: instance variable @opening_hours_tuesday_to not initialized
(eval):11: warning: instance variable @opening_hours_wednesday_from not initialized
(eval):2: warning: instance variable @opening_hours_wednesday_to not initialized
(eval):11: warning: instance variable @opening_hours_thursday_from not initialized
(eval):2: warning: instance variable @opening_hours_thursday_to not initialized
(eval):11: warning: instance variable @opening_hours_friday_from not initialized
(eval):2: warning: instance variable @opening_hours_friday_to not initialized
(eval):11: warning: instance variable @opening_hours_saturday_from not initialized
(eval):2: warning: instance variable @opening_hours_saturday_to not initialized
```

Edit:

I ultimately ended up upgrading to rails 4. All the warnings are gone.

Comment: Which Ruby version did the project use before? Why are you not using the same version as in the original project? Don't create more troubles for yourself than you need to create.

Comment: That was `2.0.0-p481`. I'll give that a shot.

Comment: I remember now why I upgraded: `WARNING: ruby-2.0.0-p481 is past its end of life and is now unsupported.
It no longer receives bug fixes or critical security updates.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three (other) options to get rid of the warning:

1. Downgrade Ruby until the warning goes away. You're using an old version of Rails which was created before Ruby 2.2. `File.exists?` was deprecated sometime before Ruby 2.2.
2. Manually edit the offending lines in your gem repository.
3. Run a mass search and replace shell command in your gem repository:
   https://superuser.com/questions/428493/how-can-i-do-a-recursive-find-and-replace-from-the-command-line

...and of course the final option: upgrade Rails.

Comment: I downgraded to Ruby 2. Now I get a a lot of other warnings as well. I suspect I have something that does some madness with my tests. `(eval):11: warning: instance variable @opening_hours_monday_from not initialized` for instance.

Comment: @Hendrik Ouch..sounds complicated :-/

Comment: You can try running it as `RUBYOPT="-W0" rake test`

Comment: @max Thx. See last line of his question.

Comment: @max why do I have to this? I never had to do this before in other rails projects.

Comment: Turning off warnings and downgrading software is a *last resort*. I hope upgrading is a possibility. You're exposing yourself to huge amounts of risk here.

Comment: @Hendrik As I explained. You have an old(er) Rails version with a new(er) Ruby version. `File.exists?` was deprecated, but it's used in the old Rails version still. Just edit the gem files, that's what I would do (though this depends on if this project is only a local project or a shared/deployable project. If the project is shared then editing gem files directly is not a good idea).